# Can this mysql insert be sped up?

Tags: php, optimization, insert, mysqli

This `insert` is a part of my application that allows  the user to take photos and store them in the database. There's a pretty specific naming convention for all the filenames being stored in the database, which is why my insert has such intense `case` statements. I'm guessing this has something to do with my slow performance. When inserting new `shots` for a `patient` with very few, or no, `shots` stored in the database, my application runs much faster. However, if the `patient` I'm adding `shots` to has already has a lot stored in the database, the performance is much slower.

Is it possible to speed up this `insert` statement? If so, how? My app is coded in PHP and I'm using `phpMyAdmin` and `mysqli`

```
INSERT INTO shot (ID, VISIT_ID, PATIENT_ID ,IMG_FILENAME ,SHRUNK_IMG_FILENAME ,SUBDIR ,SUBSUBDIR ,IMG_FILE_FORMAT ,EYE)
SELECT (
        SELECT (max(ID) + 1)  FROM SHOT
        )
      ,(
        SELECT max(ID)  FROM visit  WHERE visit.patient_id = " . $_SESSION['id'] ."
        )
    ," . $_SESSION['id'] . "
    ,(
        SELECT CASE 
            WHEN ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM shot ) < 100
                    THEN CONCAT ( '00000000' ,(MAX(shot.ID) + 1) ,'r.jpg' )
            WHEN ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM shot ) < 1000
                    AND ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM SHOT ) > 99
                    THEN CONCAT ( '0000000' ,(MAX(shot.ID) + 1) ,'r.jpg' )
            WHEN ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM shot ) < 10000
                    AND ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM SHOT ) > 999
                    THEN CONCAT ( '000000' ,(MAX(shot.ID) + 1) ,'r.jpg' )
            WHEN ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM shot ) < 100000
                    AND ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM SHOT ) > 9999
                    THEN CONCAT ( '00000' ,(MAX(shot.ID) + 1) ,'r.jpg' )
            WHEN ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM shot ) < 1000000
                    AND ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM SHOT ) > 99999
                    THEN CONCAT ( '0000' ,(MAX(shot.ID) + 1) ,'r.jpg' )
            WHEN ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM shot ) < 10000000
                    AND ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM SHOT ) > 999999
                    THEN CONCAT ( '000' ,(MAX(shot.ID) + 1) ,'r.jpg' )
            WHEN ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM shot ) < 100000000
                    AND ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM SHOT ) > 9999999
                    THEN CONCAT ( '00' ,(MAX(shot.ID) + 1) ,'r.jpg' )
            WHEN ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM shot ) < 1000000000
                    AND ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM SHOT ) > 99999999
                    THEN CONCAT ( '0' ,(MAX(shot.ID) + 1) ,'r.jpg' )
            WHEN ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM shot ) < 10000000000
                    AND ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM SHOT ) > 999999999
                    THEN CONCAT ( (MAX(shot.ID) + 1) ,'r.jpg' )
            WHEN ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM shot ) < 100000000000
                    AND ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM SHOT ) > 9999999999
                    THEN CONCAT ( (MAX(shot.ID) + 1) ,'r.jpg' )
            END
            )
    ,(
        SELECT CASE 
            WHEN ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM shot ) < 100
                    THEN CONCAT ( '00000000' ,(MAX(shot.ID) + 1) ,'s.bmp' )
            WHEN ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM shot ) < 1000
                    AND ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM SHOT ) > 99
                    THEN CONCAT ( '0000000' ,(MAX(shot.ID) + 1) ,'s.bmp' )
            WHEN ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM shot ) < 10000
                    AND ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM SHOT ) > 999
                    THEN CONCAT ( '000000' ,(MAX(shot.ID) + 1) ,'s.bmp' )
            WHEN ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM shot ) < 100000
                    AND ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM SHOT ) > 9999
                    THEN CONCAT ( '00000' ,(MAX(shot.ID) + 1) ,'s.bmp' )
            WHEN ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM shot ) < 1000000
                    AND ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM SHOT ) > 99999
                    THEN CONCAT ( '0000' ,(MAX(shot.ID) + 1) ,'s.bmp' )
            WHEN ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM shot ) < 10000000
                    AND ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM SHOT ) > 999999
                    THEN CONCAT ( '000' ,(MAX(shot.ID) + 1) ,'s.bmp' )
            WHEN ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM shot ) < 100000000
                    AND ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM SHOT ) > 9999999
                    THEN CONCAT ( '00' ,(MAX(shot.ID) + 1) ,'s.bmp' )
            WHEN ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM shot ) < 1000000000
                    AND ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM SHOT ) > 99999999
                    THEN CONCAT ( '0' ,(MAX(shot.ID) + 1) ,'s.bmp' )
            WHEN ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM shot ) < 10000000000
                    AND ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM SHOT ) > 999999999
                    THEN CONCAT ( (MAX(shot.ID) + 1) ,'s.bmp' )
            WHEN ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM shot ) < 100000000000
                    AND ( SELECT MAX(shot.ID) + 1 FROM SHOT ) > 9999999999
                    THEN CONCAT ( (MAX(shot.ID) + 1) ,'s.bmp' )
            END
        )
    ,$SUB
    ,$ISUB
    ,'124'
    ,'0'
FROM SHOT
```

Comment: oh, yes.. gosh, it shall be changed...

Comment: LPAD - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad

Comment: Nicccee! You all are awesome, trying now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will propably be faster but at least a lot shorter.. Why use cases when you can use LPAD?

```
INSERT INTO shot (ID, VISIT_ID, PATIENT_ID ,IMG_FILENAME ,SHRUNK_IMG_FILENAME ,SUBDIR ,SUBSUBDIR ,IMG_FILE_FORMAT ,EYE)
SELECT 
    x.ID + 1,
    (
        SELECT max(ID)  FROM visit  WHERE visit.patient_id = " . $_SESSION['id'] ."
    ),
    " . $_SESSION['id'] . ",
    CONCAT (LPAD(MAX(x.ID) + 1, 10, 0), 'r.jpg'),
    CONCAT (LPAD(MAX(x.ID) + 1, 10, 0), 's.bmp'),
    $SUB,
    $ISUB,
    '124',
    '0'
FROM SHOT x
```

Comment: Never used LPAD before, or at least don't remember it from school.. My performance isn't faster, at least not noticeably. But a least my query's a lot shorter. Guess I'll have to look for something else hurting my performance.

Answer (score 1):

Replace those huge `case` statements with `lpad(MAX(shot.ID) + 1, 10, '0')` and you'll be fine.